# OWIN Self host - hook into begin request, end request events

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, asp.net-web-api2

In ASP.NET OWIN self host, how do you hook into the BeginRequest, EndRequest, Application Start and Application End events since there is no need for Global.asax.cs?

Answer (score 6):

Add a simple owin middleware at the start of the pipeline to handle begin and end request.

```
public class SimpleMiddleWare:OwinMiddleware
{
    public SimpleMiddleWare(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Begin Request");//Add begin request logic
        await Next.Invoke(context);
        Debug.WriteLine("End Request");//Add end request logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In WebAPI you can use [filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) for that. You can override `OnActionExecuting` and `OnActionExecuted`. If you don't want to annotate every single controller, you can add your filter als a global filter:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new MyFilterAttribute());
```

As replacement for `ApplicationStart` you can execute your code in your `OwinStartup` class. I don't know whether there is something similar to `ApplicationEnd`.